# Spawn prefabs according to player platform with LobbyManager

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I'm trying to spawn different prefabs depending on the player platform. So I'm overriding the NetworkLobbyManager to spawn objects the way I want. So I create a Dictionnary that associates a connectionId to an index of a prefab and then I instantiate a prefab according to this index.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class LobbyManager : NetworkLobbyManager
{
    private Dictionary<int, int> m_currentPlayers;

    void Start()
    {
        m_currentPlayers = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    }

    void AddPlayer(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsPlayer)
        {
            m_currentPlayers.Add(conn.connectionId, 0);
        }
        else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            m_currentPlayers.Add(conn.connectionId, 1);
        }
    }

    public override GameObject OnLobbyServerCreateLobbyPlayer(NetworkConnection conn, short playerControllerId)
    {
        AddPlayer(conn);

        return base.OnLobbyServerCreateLobbyPlayer(conn, playerControllerId);
    }

    public override GameObject OnLobbyServerCreateGamePlayer(NetworkConnection conn, short playerControllerId)
    {
        GameObject go = Instantiate(spawnPrefabs[m_currentPlayers[conn.connectionId]]);
        NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, go, playerControllerId);

        return go;
    }
}
```

But with this code the spawn player on the clients is always the same as the host and I don't know why because it seems like I'm overriding the correct functions and I saw here http://abrgame.blogspot.fr/2016/01/using-unet-to-spawn-different-player.html a guy who used the same technique and that works for him...

Answer (score 0):

### Your Problem

```cs
if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsPlayer)
{
    m_currentPlayers.Add(conn.connectionId, 0);
}
else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
{
    m_currentPlayers.Add(conn.connectionId, 1);
}
```

The `NetworkLobbyManager` component behaves differently when started as a client or a host, but ultimately, if i am correct, the host handles the player spawning. In your code that means, **the component only looks at its own platform, not at the platforms of the connecting players**.

### Possible Solution

You need to pass the information about the connecting player's platform to the host. You can create a derived class of `NetworkConnection` that retrieves and carries the platform information, a derived class of `NetworkClient` which uses your custom `NetworkConnection`class, and ultimately adjust your own `NetworkLobbyManager` derived class to extract the platform information and use it.

```cs
//NetworkClient

public class MyNetworkClient: NetworkClient
{
    public MyNetworkClient() : base()
    {
        SetNetworkConnectionClass<MyNetworkConnection>();
    }
}

//NetworkConnection class

public class MyNetworkConnection : NetworkConnection
{
    private RuntimePlatform connectionPlatform;

    public MyNetworkConnection() : base()
    {
        connectionPlatform = Application.platform;
    }

    public RuntimePlatform ConnectionPlatform { get { return connectionPlatform; } }
}

// Suggested adjustment for your NetworkLobbyManagerClass

void AddPlayer(MyNetworkConnection conn)
{
    // I like switches, it's a question of taste imo
    switch(conn.ConnectionPlatform)
    {
        case RuntimePlatform.Android:
            m_currentPlayers.Add(conn.connectionId, 1);
            break;
        case RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor:
        case RuntimePlatform.WindowsPlayer:
        default:
            m_currentPlayers.Add(conn.connectionId, 0);
    }
}

public override GameObject OnLobbyServerCreateLobbyPlayer(NetworkConnection conn, short playerControllerId)
{
    // Explicitely pass your custom class
    AddPlayer(conn as MyNetworkConnection);
    return base.OnLobbyServerCreateLobbyPlayer(conn, playerControllerId);
}

public override GameObject OnLobbyServerCreateGamePlayer(NetworkConnection conn, short playerControllerId)
{
    GameObject go = Instantiate(spawnPrefabs[m_currentPlayers[conn.connectionId]]);
    NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, go, playerControllerId);

    return go;
}
```

I'd like to hear from you whether it worked. :)

Edited: Since `MyNetworkConnection` inherits from `NetworkConnection`, it should be able to be passed as a `NetworkConnection` parameter. That means, you can leave your overriden methods as they are, however you need to explicitely pass your `MyNetworkConnection` class to your `AddPlayer` method.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time, but visual is complaining about the overriding method OnLobbySerevrCreateLobbyPlayer because of the MyNetworkConnection parameter
And also, what are the base() in MyNetworkClient ?

Comment: `base()` refers to the constructor of the inherited class. I have updated my answer, please review.

Comment: I've updated according your modifications. It says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object
LobbyManager.AddPlayer (.MyNetworkConnection conn) (at Assets/Scripts/LobbyManager.cs:42)"
because it did not find "setNetworkConnectionClass(conn);" I replaced it by SetNetworkConnectionClass<MyNetworkConnection>() so maybe it's that.

Comment: I also removed the "this()" because it was struggling on it in visual

Comment: Yeah, I spotted it. The method is called `SetNetworkConnectionClass()`, I had a typo. :( Also instead of `this()` `base()` should work.

Comment: So I replaced it with SetNetworkConnectionClass<MyNetworkConnection>()
Is it good ?

Comment: You can do that, but you must pass your custom class as a parameter too (as written above): `SetNetworkConnectionClass<MyNetworkConnection>(conn);`

Comment: Yeah, but SetNetworkConnectionClass(conn); do not work be cause the SetNetworkConnectionClass needs to be something like SetNetworkConnectionClass<T>()

Comment: Unity's documentation is at it again :') Still it should work, as my suggested `MyNetworkConnection` class pulls the platform directly from `Application.platform`. Did you test it?

Comment: Yep, but it can't compile because of SetNetworkConnectionClass<MyNetworkConnection>(conn);
"
No overload for method `SetNetworkConnectionClass' takes `1' arguments

Comment: I have updated my answer again, and adjusted some code based on your findings.

Comment: I have updated according to your modifications. Everything compiles but fails here : `switch (conn.ConnectionPlatform)`
ullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
LobbyManager.AddPlayer (.MyNetworkConnection conn) (at Assets/Scripts/LobbyManager.cs:39)

Comment: Where do you keep your method to connect as a client?

Comment: Wut ? I just have this component with the methods you gave.
Sorry, it's the first time I'm working with the LobbyManager ^^

Comment: Yes, but how do your players connect to the lobby?

Comment: They use the GUI provided with NetworkManagerGUI
So they just have to use LAN Host or LAN Client (with an ip address) to join a lobby

Comment: The standard NetworkManagerHUD won't cut it for your purpose, as it seems to use the standard `NetworkManager` component, which in turn creates a regular `NetworkClient` upon invoking `StartClient()`. Updating my answer.